# How to access json object fetched by ajax in the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a sinatra app accessing an api via ajax jsonp. I can access/view the returned json in the console but I can't access it from the dom, where I need it to populate a table.
I thought I could add it as a html5 data-attribute but can't get it to work, this is my nonworking part

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
      $("#mydata").attr("data-mydata",data);
```

access from the console works, can't access it from the dom!

Comment: Is data a string or an object?

Comment: DOM/HTML attributes can only contain strings. Also, FYI, [there is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @Musa jQuery.ajax success callback uses the string returned from the request.

Comment: @Brendan: You can not generalize that. It can already be parsed if JSON was sent. Especially when JSONP is used, an object/array (anything actually) is directly passed to the success callback, no JSON or any other text are in play.

Comment: it's an object in the console

Comment: @FelixKling Ah yes very true - I have a habit of specifying the datatype rather than leaving it to jQuery so I forgot that it can be "smart" about it!

Comment: @raphael_turtle If you want to specically use the data returned as a string you can set the dataType  to text

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery data [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g5CWK/)

Dom attribute can only contain string. but jQuery.data can hold any type of data.

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
      $("#mydata").data("mydata",data);
}
```

Access it using jQuery.data

```
$("#mydata").data("mydata");
```

Comment: that just gives me an undefined

Comment: @raphael_turtle. you may trying to access it before ajax complete.

Comment: how would I wait until it completes?

Comment: provide a callback method to ajax success or try to access it inside any event eg. click, mouseover but make sure that this ajax is already called

Comment: how do I implement the callback?

Comment: you can provide a function to success as success:callback; you can define this callback method anywhere. this will get called when ever ajax will complete

Comment: doesn't work, I can still access it in the console but can't attatch it to the dom

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for me?

Comment: I sort of have it working but it needs to be wrapped in a window.onload function, is that normal?